# Nuvem de palavras no R

Tags: r

Estou usando o seguinte programa:

```
library("wordcloud")
library("tm")
library("RColorBrewer")
dados=read.csv("C:/teste/dados.csv", sep=";", dec=",",header=TRUE) 
capa=dados$mensagem
corpus  <- VCorpus(VectorSource(capa))
corpus1  <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus2  <- tm_map(corpus1, tolower)
corpus2  <- tm_map(corpus2, removePunctuation)
wordcloud(corpus2, random.order = F, colors = brewer.pal(5, "Dark2"))
```

E está dando o seguinte erro:

> Erro: inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE

Answer (score 4):

Eu queria comentar mas não posso ainda, você precisa do vetor com as palavras em formato de texto o que aparece se você faz isso `class(capa)`? Esta é a forma como eu faço:

```
texto = readLines("cloud.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")

texto = Corpus(VectorSource(texto))

texto <- tm_map(texto, stripWhitespace)

texto <- tm_map(texto, tolower)

texto <- tm_map(texto, removeWords, stopwords("portuguese"))

texto <- tm_map(texto, stemDocument)

wordcloud(texto, scale=c(5,0.5), max.words=100, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))

m = TermDocumentMatrix(texto, control = list(minWordLength = 1))

m = as.matrix(m)

v = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
```

Se quiser algo mais completo da uma olhada nesse [link](https://georeferenced.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/rwordcloud/)

Comment: Obrigada. Eu fiz uma transformação e deu certo. Use o seguinte comando: corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))

Comment: @user20273, responda sua própria pergunta ! assim fica registrado o seu problema, eu ia responder, so estava preparando o ambiente do R xD

Answer (score 2):

É só usar uma transformação, que o problema é resolvido:

```
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```